# How this is working in agda?

Tags: agda

I want to prove that there exist a natural number which is less than 10. I write the code in this way..

```
thm2 : (∃ λ m → (m < 10))
thm2 = zero , s≤s z≤n
```

I am not able to understand how this is working. Please explain..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's dissect `thm2`.

### The type of the expression

```
∃ λ m → m < 10
```

[`∃`](http://agda.github.io/agda-stdlib/Data.Product.html#823) is defined in Data.Product as an alias for [`Σ`](http://agda.github.io/agda-stdlib/Data.Product.html#439) where the first argument is left implicit. This means that `∃` is taking an element `B` of type `A → Set` and returning the type of pairs containing an `a` of type `A` and a `b` of type `B a`.

Now, `λ m → m < 10` is taking an `m` in `ℕ` and returning the type of proofs that `m < 10`.

So `∃ λ m → m < 10` is the type of pairs of an `ℕ` and a proof that it is less than `10`.

### The expression itself

```
zero , s≤s z≤n
```

For the whole thing to typecheck, we need:

`zero` to be a `ℕ` which it is.

`s≤s z≤n` to be a proof that `0 < 10`. [`_<_`](http://agda.github.io/agda-stdlib/Data.Nat.Base.html#1111) is defined in `Data.Nat.Base` as an alias for `λ m n → suc m ≤ n`. So proving that `0 < 10` is the same as proving that `1 ≤ 10`.

Now, [`_≤_`](http://agda.github.io/agda-stdlib/Data.Nat.Base.html#604) is an inductive type with two constructors:

- a base case [`z≤n`](http://agda.github.io/agda-stdlib/Data.Nat.Base.html#635) saying that `0` is less than or equal to all natural numbers
- a step case [`s≤s`](http://agda.github.io/agda-stdlib/Data.Nat.Base.html#677) saying that if one number is less than or equal to another, then their `suc`s also are less than or equal.

The proof `s≤s z≤n` is indeed a valid proof that `1 ≤ 10`: `z≤n` proves that `0 ≤ 9` and `s≤s` concludes that therefore `1 ≤ 10`.